# Badge "Curious" not getting awarded/updated. Is this a bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

So this particular badge "Curious" on my profile seems to be "stuck" since last two days.

Yesterday despite reaching 5/5 it was neither awarded nor updated.
Today the same status despite it reaching 6/5.

Usually the badges are updated within 12-24 hours. But this seems to be a bug.

Am I missing something here?

Screenshot:[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you didn't fulfill the second requirement yet

> Asked a well-received question on 5 separate days, **and maintained a positive question record**

And you have 1 deleted question with bad score, so you didn't maintain a positive question record yet. This confusion happen a lot, refer below mentioned main meta for details:

[Why I haven't I received the “Curious” badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263351/why-i-havent-i-received-the-curious-badge)

Anyway you can still earn it, by asking new good questions.

Comment: *didn't maintain

Comment: Also mentioend under the tag status : http://i.stack.imgur.com/wATg8.png

Comment: Yes I knew about the second condition. Though I misunderstood the positive record part.

Comment: @PaleBlueDot As a side note, you don't actually have to delete questions that were closed as duplicate but are otherwise totally well-phrased and valid questions. A good duplicate question is actually not a bad thing and serves as an additional pointer to a question. That is also why duplicates are exempt from the automatic cleanup routines that delete closed questions.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Sure. I don't delete questions if they are duplicate on SE. Only when it's off-topic or something similar. E.g. this question of mine: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60431/which-movie-had-the-most-accurate-depiction-of-the-joker-from-dc-comics

Personally I don't find any reason to keep off-topic or similar closed question. Hence (I think) it is best to delete them and reduce the junk on the website.

Comment: @PaleBlueDot he is talking about this one : http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53066/what-all-techniques-are-used-to-display-blood-in-films-television-shows

Comment: @PaleBlueDot Well sure, that question was closed and downvoted and should thus definitely be deleted. I was talking about duplicate questions that haven't been downvoted.

Comment: @AnkitSharma, Napoleon oh yeah. Totally forgot about that one. Why am I not seeing that question in my list of questions (which also include deleted questions)?

Comment: @PaleBlueDot Because your list of questions does *not* include deleted questions. There is an additional link to show "deleted recent questions" but this only goes back a limited time.

Comment: Anyway I undeleted that one

Comment: Is there any way to check that score? Because as far as I remember I had 1 question that was downvoted, closed and deleted, but I have 12 other good questions, and I don't know why I still haven't received this badge.